# Find limit of a complex function

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

Does it exist? if it exists, how to find the below limit:
$$\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}z\log\left(\sin \pi z\right)=?$$,where $z \in \Bbb{C}$

Comment: @DominicMichaelis,thank you to point out, I am sorry .I means $z$ is a complex number ,not a integer.

Comment: @GitGud,sorry, I mean $z \in \Bbb{C}$,thanks for point out.

Comment: Strictly speaking, $\log(\sin \pi z)$ is multivalued and has arbitrarily large values, so the limit doesn't exist.  If you stick to e.g. the principal branch of $\log$, or any branch whose imaginary part is bounded, there is a limit.  However, you could approach the origin on a path that winds tightly enough that, for a branch of $\log$ that is continuous on this path, the limit does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Use that $\sin(\pi z)\approx \pi z $ if $|z|$ is small. So your limit is the same as 
$$\lim_{z\to 0} z \cdot \log(\pi z)$$ 
Write it in a form in which you can use L'hospitale.